# How can I make this matrix in python without using numpy?

Tags: python, matrix

I have to make a matrix thats N by N and the example im given looks like this:

```
4 0 0 0
3 3 0 0
2 2 2 0
1 1 1 1
```

So what I get from the example is that its gonna take the number N is (4 in this example since its 4 by 4) and print the number on the top row first column then fill it with zeros and then go down one line and print N -1 in the first two columns and then zeros.
My code looks like this atm:

```
def fill_matrix(n): #Fills the matrix with 0s
    # Llena la matriz
    for r in range(n):
        row = []
        for c in range(n):
            row.append(0)
        matrix.append(fila)
    return matrix

def print_matrix(matriz): #Prints the matrix
    rows = len(matriz)
    columns = len(matriz[0])
    for f in range(row):
        for c in range(columns):
            print ("%3d" %matrix[f][c], end="")
        print()
       
# Programa principal
side = int(input("Input the size of the matrix: ")) #Input of N by N
while side < 1:
    print("Size must be bigger than 0")
    side = int(input("Input the size of the matrix: "))
matrix = []
fill_matrix(side)
print_matrix(matrix)
```

How can I make this matrix look like the one in the exercise?

Comment: Could you please translate your code to English? There's also a Spanish-speaking site if you'd prefer: https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Break the problem down a bit. Could you write a function that can be called like this: `build_row(filled_with=3, count=2, empty_value=0)`, such that it returns `[3, 3, 0, 0]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use list comprehension:

```
N = 4
>>> [[N-i]*(i+1)+[0]*(N-i-1) for i in range(N)]
[[4, 0, 0, 0], [3, 3, 0, 0], [2, 2, 2, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

In a function:

```
def fill_matrix(N):
    return [[N-i]*(i+1)+[0]*(N-i-1) for i in range(N)]

def print_matrix(m):
    print("\n".join(["\t".join(map(str, row)) for row in m]))

>>> fill_matrix(6)
[[6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0],
 [3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0],
 [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]

>>> print_matrix(fill_matrix(6))
6   0   0   0   0   0
5   5   0   0   0   0
4   4   4   0   0   0
3   3   3   3   0   0
2   2   2   2   2   0
1   1   1   1   1   1
```

The ith row consists of:

1. The number N-i repeated i+1 times
2. 0 repeated N-(i+1) times

Comment: Do I have to replace the original fill_matrix function with this new one? or just make a new function with this?

Comment: You can replace it since your function just fills in zeros

Comment: Thanks I got it, can you explain to me how the print function works? Ive seen map, /n and /t but I didnt really understand when should I use them or whats the advantage of using them

Comment: You print function should work fine too. This is just a *complicated* list comprehension converting each row to a string separated by tabs, and then combining the rows  to a string separated by newlines.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the [excellent approach by @not_speshal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69307140/4755954), slight more readability can be achieved with `reversed(range())`

```
n = 4

[[i+1]*(n-i)+[0]*(i) for i in reversed(range(n))]
```

```
[[4, 0, 0, 0], 
 [3, 3, 0, 0], 
 [2, 2, 2, 0], 
 [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

not_speshal has already given you the list-comprehension solution, but you might find it easier to understand the logic by writing a full loop.
Let's analyze the matrix you want:

```
Row #   Value   Count
0       4       1
1       3       2
2       2       3
3       1       4
# General case:
i       (N - i) (i + 1)
```

So your `i`th row needs to contain the number `N - i`, `i + 1` times, and then the rest should be zeros.

```
def fill_matrix(N):
    # First, let's create a matrix of zeros
    matrix = [ [0] * N for _ in range(N) ]
    
    # Now, iterate over rows
    for i in range(N):
        # Set the first (i + 1) values to (N - i)
        for j in range(i + 1):
            matrix[i][j] = N - i

    return matrix
```

To run this:

```
>>> fill_matrix(4)
 [[4, 0, 0, 0], 
  [3, 3, 0, 0], 
  [2, 2, 2, 0], 
  [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

If you want to reduce the iterations by getting rid of the zeros-matrix creation, but you will have to append zeros to fill out each row after the `for j in range(i + 1)` loop.

```
def fill_matrix(N):
    # An empty list that will contain our rows
    matrix = []

    # Now, iterate over rows
    for i in range(N):
        row = []
        # Set the first (i + 1) values to (N - i)
        for _ in range(i + 1):
            row.append(N - i)
        # Set the remaining values to 0
        for _ in range(N - len(row)):
            row.append(0)
        matrix.append(row)
    return matrix
```